# cmder how to use fancy (new?) suggestions while typing

Tags: cmder

How can I use the suggestions shown in cmder?

[image]

I tried some combinations with tab (control tab etc) but can't seem to find the button that actually completes the line with the (correct!) suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press Right arrow key to use auto completion
[cmder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2YDH.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).